# Merging row in gridview control

Tags: vb.net, gridview, html-table

I need to merge two rows asp.net gridview control in the runtime. Any suggestion?

Comment: Suggestion - add more detail to your question (any two rows?  Two rows that meet a certain criteria? etc).

Comment: I need to group a set of data which is retieved from a lingdatasource into the grid view. I want to group my results based on customer name. eg: a customer could have serveral reminders sent I am grouping the date sent and the description on customer name.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at posts/tutorials on merging cells of `GridView`.

1. [Rows and Columns Merging in ASP.NET GridView Control](http://weblogs.asp.net/brijmohan/archive/2011/09/03/rows-and-columns-merging-in-asp-net-gridview-control.aspx)
2. [Cell Merging In GridView](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/aspnet/Merge_cells_in_GridView.aspx)